# Button active state based on SQL query

Tags: php, html, pdo

I'm trying to learn up PHP and HTML and I've gotten stuck.

I have a PHP PDO SQL query

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT FROM tbl WHERE Staff ID='$staff_id';");
$stmt->execute();`
```

I would like to add this to a table cell containing a form submit, below:

```
<td>
    <form action='staff_view_by_id.php?name="<?php echo $row['staff_id']; ?>"' method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="staff_id" value="<?php echo $row['staff_id'] ?>">
        <input type="submit" id="staff_list_submit" name="submit" value="View"> 
    </form>
```

I'd like to have something that would cause that View button to be disabled if the result of the SQL Count is zero.

Is there a way to do this? I'm guessing it would be an if statement of some kind, but so far I can't get it to work.

Thanks

Comment: First of all, you need to change your "COUNT" to "COUNT(*)". Also, you don't select staff_id from table.

Comment: In addition to the comment about `COUNT` should be `COUNT(id)` and that you're not selecting the `staff_id` column, you also need to fetch the results. Then you should parameterize your query to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: And you are missing a semicolon after the echo of your staff id

Comment: I was missing the semicolon.  I'll read up some more on the SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
<input type="submit" id="staff_list_submit" name="submit" value="View" disabled="<?php if($result === 0){echo true;} else {echo false;} ?>">
```

Comment: I tried this and it disables the button all the time, even if my statement should echo true

Comment: Try to put the whole disabled attribute in your echo

Comment: `<input type="submit" id="staff_list_submit" name="submit" value="View" <?php if($result === 0){echo disabled;} ?>>`